# Regular expression for not allowing special char at end and the string length should be in between 3-25

Tags: jquery, regex, regular-language

I want to write a regular expression using jQuery to validate input fields which will not allow special char at end and the string length should be in between 3-25.

currently I have an expression which will not allow special char at the end

```
([0-9a-zA-Z\s])$
```

for length I tried

```
([0-9a-zA-Z\s])${3,25}
```

but getting error preceding character is not quantifiable.

some valid inputs

```
abc#123
a%scsd
```

Invalid Inputs

```
abc453&
ab
123%
```

Comment: `.{2,24}[0-9a-zA-Z\s]$`, maybe? By the looks of it you could use a regex tutorial.

Comment: @ali i think space is a special character. did you want to allow space and `$` at the end `([0-9a-zA-Z\s\$])$` ?

Comment: Sorry forgot to remove $ and space is allowed

Comment: @Biffen I already tried that one it is not working

Comment: @ali786 In what way does it not work? Granted it needs a `^` at the beginning, but when I try it with your samples it works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead to check if  a line contain a special character at the last or not. And also use a positive lookahead to specify that the string length must be from 3 to 25. The below regexes would match the strings only if both conditions are satisfied.

```
(?!.*[\W_]$)(?=^.{3,25}$).*
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/oR8dY9/2)

OR

```
(?=.*[A-Za-z0-9]$)(?=^.{3,25}$).*
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/oR8dY9/3)

Answer (score 1):

You need to check it like this

```
^(.{2,24}[0-9a-zA-Z])$
```

`.{2,24}` allows any characters (at least 2, up to 24) and `[0-9a-zA-Z]` restricts the last character to alpha-numeric.

Answer (score 1):

```
(?!.*[!@#$%^&*]$)^.{3,25}$
```

Try this. You can add more special characters if you want. see demo.

http://regex101.com/r/qC9cH4/8

Comment: I am not downvoted, This is also correct but I can't go for what is not allow I can go for what is allowed as there are lot of special char which i don't know.